# how can i make my jump animation and fall animation to work in godot 4.2? when i press jump it doesnt play the animation and when it fall, the same

Tags: godot-4

this is the code im using

```
    extends CharacterBody2D


@export var SPEED = 200.0
@export var JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

func _physics_process(delta):
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("fall")

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("jump")

    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
    if velocity.x > 0 and is_on_floor_only() or velocity.x < 0 and is_on_floor_only():
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("run")
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("idle")
    

    if direction:
        if direction < 0:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = true
            $AnimatedSprite2D.position.x = -20
        else:
            $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = false
            $AnimatedSprite2D.position.x = 20
    
    

    move_and_slide()
```

can someone help me please T-T

Comment: I'd expect your code to do one frame of the jump animation and then do the fall animation, is that correct?

Comment: yep it just play one single frame

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess. (I don't know if this is how it works though). You press the jump button and it plays the jump animation, but later down the road it checks if it is touching the ground and either plays the "run" or "idle" animation, and since it doesn't move until `move_and_slide()`, it is still touching the ground. Here's what I suggest.

```
if not is_on_floor() and velocity.y > 0:
   $AnimatedSprite2D.play("jump")
elif not is_on_floor() and velocity.y > 0:
   $AnimatedSprite2D.play("fall")
```

This may or may not fix it.
(I am not 100% sure this will work, but it's something)

Comment: thanks for the help. i had switched to godot 4 and manage to fix the problem lol, but still thanks!